# Using S3 Java SDK to talk to S3 compatible storage (minio)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to use aws-sdk-java AwsS3client to talk to a minio storage. From the CLI I am able to do:

```
aws --profile=minioplay  --endpoint-url https://play.minio.io:9000 s3 cp logback.xml s3://miniohstest-jixusroqeb --debug
```

thus using a non default profile and a custom endpoint.
Not sure how to do this (would I be able to ?) from the java sdk.
I roughly translated the above `awscli` command to this scala snippet :

```
val cred = ...
val endpoint = "https://play.minio.io:9000"
val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withCredentials(cred)
      .withEndpointConfiguration(
        new EndpointConfiguration(
          endpoint,
          AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegion(endpoint, AmazonS3Client.S3_SERVICE_NAME)
        )
      )
      .build()
```

Using the above client I am only able to make very simple requests such as :

```
client.listBuckets().asScala.foreach(println(_))
```

which works. But when I try to do something advanced such as :

```
val listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
      .withBucketName("miniohstest-jixusroqeb")
      //.withPrefix(r.getURI.getPath)
      //.withDelimiter(delimiter)

val res = client.listObjects(listRequest)
res.getObjectSummaries.forEach(x => println(x.getKey))
```

it throws the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: miniohstest-jixusroqeb.play.minio.io
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I resolved this by setting `withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)`.